# Referencing ResourceDictionary from WP 7.1 project in WP 8.0 project

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary

I have a Windows Phone Class Library project ("WPLib"), that is targeting Windows Phone OS 7.1. In this project I have a folder ("ResourceDictionaries") which contains a resource dictionary ("ColorsAndBrushes.xaml") with the following content:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have a Windows Phone Application project targeting Windows Phone OS 8.0 which has a reference to "WPLib", and has a resource dictionary of its own with the following content:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/WPLib;component/ResourceDictionaries/ColorsAndBrushes.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This results in the following error:

*"Resource Dictionary ‘/WPLib;component/ResourceDictionaries/ColorsAndBrushes.xaml’ defined in a 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71' project cannot be used in a     'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0' project."*

Is there a remedy to this issue other than adding the original resource dictionary as a link to the WP8 application project? (Note - the class library must remain targeted to WP 7.1)

Comment: Take a look at Portable Class Library - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx This might help.

Comment: @OndraMorský In my PCL, I have been unable to add a ResourceDictionary through the UI or manually.